# Gmail only prints embedded pics in greyscale

Tags: gmail, images, printing

I have printed embedded coloured pictures from Gmail happily in colour, but now it's changed so that while I can still see them on the screen in colour, when I print them they preview and print in greyscale.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that your print settings are set to greyscale. Now, I can't provide specific advice, because each printer driver / manufacturer presents the options in slightly different ways, but it's common for a color printer to offer the option to convert to greyscale (in order to save on [CMY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) ink, for instance). Try exploring the print dialog's dark, deep corners to see if some greyscale option accidentally or spontaneously got turned on.

Of course, this could be a completely unrelated issue. One clue is to see if there are any other color elements on the page which are also turning grey, and to test printing from other websites.